# Threejs High poly model 2d canvas text

Tags: canvas, three.js

Firstly , I love been using three js. But i need little help about what i am trying. 
I have high poly model on maya and i exported it to js and loaded via THREE.JSONLoader() 
its ok so far.

But i need a solution :S 
i want to add text over that model . I tried to 2d canvas filltext and use as texture bla bla. it only fillcolor i cant see my text . I guess the problem is high poly model not a ordinary cube station :)

what must i do ? i dont wanna a solution which use 2d canvas text mapping because i need colored model over text not just text. also i need to move that text somehow ofc it must be use model geometry while moving.

any solution or ideas about that?

thanks all

sry for english, its not my primary language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who suffered with this issue , i create another object json same position with old one . and i used transparent mesh with it and create 2d canvas text on mouse coordnate position and apply this 2d canvas object as texture.